# How to optimally distinguish between linearly independent vectors in higher dimensional complex/real space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-analysis, quantum-information

I am to distinguish between 4 linearly independent vectors belonging to $\mathbb{C^{16}}$ space by creating a set of *Positive Operator Valued Measurements (POVM)* that will act on these vectors. I have found that the given set of vectors are such that there exists no projectors which can categorize them into mutually orthogonal sub-spaces under $\mathbb{C^{16}}$, so that I cannot simplify the problem as a problem in two vectors within these subspaces. The set of POVM ${\{E_i\}}$ has to follow completeness $\sum_{i=1}^nE_i=\mathbb{I}$ for some $n$ and optimally distinguish between these vectors with maximum probability possible through optimization. I tried generalizing the procedure proposed in http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/31/34/013/pdf for 4 vectors in $\mathbb{R^4}$ but it is not working out because of the fact that the cross product they used in 3 dimensions cannot be generalized in 4 or higher dimensions directly (Hurwitz Theorem, composition algebra). On page 5 of the paper they have proposed to use *outer product* for its generalization, but that is not satisfying the matrix multiplication. 
If someone may help doing the same procedure in $\mathbb{R^4}$ for four vectors, would be enough help I seek for its use in $\mathbb{C^{16}}$ space.

Comment: No, vectors are linearly independent but not othogonal.

Comment: Then, take those, extend to a basis for $\mathbb{C}^{16}$ then run the usual orthonormalization procedure and this will give you an orthonormal basis for the 4-dimensional subspace. I think the spectral theorem ought to guide the rest... but, I don't entirely understand your problem just yet.

Comment: Thanks! But the vectors cannot be orthonormalized because actually they are quantum states that cannot be disturbed independently, but can be acted upon by a set of operators only once. They cannot be orthonormalized by methods like Gram-Schmidt, that will change the vectors.

Comment: So, I am looking for a set of such operators that will make this possible wrt some optimization at cost of probability. The original given vectors themselves have to be distinguished, they cannot be altered to orthogonal vectors, the problem then will become trivial.

Comment: vectors in $\mathbb{C}^{16}$ are not like what you describe. Perhaps this is better asked in physics stackexchange?